# Java 8 code is automatically converted to some other format in intellij

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have this annoying issue that I am facing for a couple of days.

Whenever I write a code in Java 8 in Intellij, it automatically gets converted to some other format(Maybe java 11).

Below is the example :

Actual Code :

> for (Attribute attribute : attributeList) {
> System.out.println("");
> }

Converted Code :

> for val attribute : attributeList {
> System.out.println("");  }

I don't know how to get rid of it. Can someone please help.

Comment: the converted code isn't java

Comment: Is it actually being rewritten (saved into the file) or is that just a rolled-up view of the loop?

Comment: Which is your IntelliJ version? It doesn't look like a java code `for val attribute : attributeList { System.out.println(""); }`

Comment: What actions triggers this code conversion(Anything specific you are doing) ? Or after you finish writing your code, it just gets converted ?

Comment: It doesn't gets saved as a file. After I write the code it gets converted. If I double click on the code it gets back to the original one. The version I am using is 2019.3.4.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, the problem is solved. Somehow a plugin got installed. i.e. Advanced Java Folding. I disabled it and now things are perfect.